# Explain why this HTML will only work in Firefox and not any other browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

everyone. I'm about a week old beginner in HTML / CSS / Javascript. I wrote this code for a page which is intended to change colors whenever the mouse moves on the page based on 'random' RGB values with an alpha value fixed to 1, always.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $('*').mousemove(function() {
      var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

      var rgba = 'rgba(' + red + ',' + blue + ',' + green + ')';
      $('*').css('background', rgba);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

I have tried Chrome, Chromium, Vivaldi, Opera and even Internet Explorer and all of these browsers displayed a webpage with the default white background page which is unresponsive to mouse movements.

Comment: there used to a <p> with some text (duh) in it but it behaved in the same way then as well, so I removed it to display only the actual relevant bits of the code

Comment: @gurvinder372 but there is at least the body, which will be selected allright, not a problem here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you're setting an RGBA colour, but you forgot to provide the A value.

I'd also suggest you use `document` to listen for the `mousemove` event and update the `background-color` of the `body`. Using the wildcard `*` selector should be avoided where possible as it's slow - especially when attaching event handlers.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function() {
  var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

  var rgba = 'rgba(' + red + ',' + blue + ',' + green + ',1)'; // note '1' at the end
  $('body').css('background', rgba);
});
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
```

This snippet should probably have an epilepsy warning...

Comment: In Firefox, perhaps, as it assumes you meant to add it. But other browsers take the value literally, and if it's not correctly formed - as in your example in the question - the setting is ignored. This is why you *need* to include the alpha value.

Comment: @RajdeepBiswas It's not in your code, please try to be more grateful. I can confirm Rory's snippet works in Chrome.

Comment: Instead of adding the Alpha, just switch to rgb()